# Setup timezone for server

Tags: date-time, time-zone, django, json

I have a server on Berlin for example, but i have clients in all over the world for an application that provides APIs for Android and iOS. Now I'm confused how should i save the times in the database and which time zone should i set for the server? How system know about clients time zone and changes the time for based on his timezone? Should i control the timezone on my django codes and change it?!

- just remember that, i dont have website(Its just a rest framework) on it(yet), its just Json data transfer

Does the system changes the time or the django does?

Because every time that i save time at the moment, when application gets the time, the time is for 3 hours ago!

Comment: http://utceverywhere.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use UTC everywhere. Configure your server in UTC timezone, use UTC when storing dates in a database, exchange the data as UTC with timezone indication, up to your applications on smartphones, and let the applications on each device turn the UTC timestamp into some local timestamp.